# changing schema for external table & continuous-data export simultaneously in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Say I have an external table 't' and a Continuous-Data Export entity 'e' already set up and functioning smoothly -- now I want to change the schema , so I need to alter both, 't' & 'e' -- so I am guessing that the order of change will be that I need to alter external table 't' first and then the export entity 'e' -- but these steps will have to be in sequence so there will be some time lag where schema defined for t & e will be out of sync. The first question I have is -- is this allowed? The second concern is -- is it safe to try in the time window when we know that export is not taking place exactly at that point in time? Does Kusto allow it?

Comment: I figured that one can't update schema of an existing external table -- one needs to drop it -- Kusto seems to be allowing dropping of an external table while some continuous-export entity is pointing to it. So one can drop external table first, recreate a new external table with updated schema and then alter continuous-export entity also to have the updated schema. At least all this Kusto allows. Whether the resulting data from this updated continuous-export will include new schema is still a question to me. I will test it.

Comment: Update -- yes what I described in the comment does indeed work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, altering a schema of an external table is not supported. This is due to the fact that *reading* from an external table (which is currently not supported, but will be in the future), is not supported when the table contains multiple schemas. Your suggestion of dropping the external table and recreating it with different schema, and then modifying the continuous export query to match the new schema should work, but it may result in some continuous export failures during the short period of time in which the continuous export still exports the old schema which doesn't match the new external table schema. This will not result in data loss for the continuous export, but may report a transient failure. Another recommended approach is to simply create a new external table, instead of dropping the old one, and alter the continuous export to point to the new table with the new query of the new schema. That should work fine and not report any failures, as the continuous export table and query are altered in the same transaction.